# Rpy2 command history

Tags: python, rpy2

Is it possible to get the R singleton command line history in Rpy2?

I have tried:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
print(ro.r('history()')
```

and also:

```
ro.r('savehistory("hist.Rhistory")')
```

but I just receive a NULL value or a blank file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `history()` displays the history rather than return the history (as a vector of strings, for example).

To capture that output, one can write a custom callback (see
http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/callbacks.html#write-console ) or use R's `sink()`.